# Fortran IF statement with numbers/labels rather than another statement

Tags: fortran, fortran90

What does this Fortran code mean:

```
   IF (J1-3) 20, 20, 21
21 J1 = J1 - 3
20 IF (J2-3) 22, 22, 23
23 J2 = J2 - 3
22 CONTINUE
```

I've seen in old project and I don't have any idea what this IF with numbers (labels) means.

Comment: It's was not that strange in the early days of FORTRAN - it was _the only_ conditional statement available in the language then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an [arithmetic `if` statement](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-11.html#sh-11.4) from FORTRAN 77. Adapted from the FORTRAN 77 specification (emphasis mine):

> The form of an arithmetic `IF` statement is:
>
> `IF (e) s1  , s2  , s2`
>
> - where: `e` is an integer, real, or double precision expression
> - `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` are each the statement label of an executable statement that appears in the same program unit as the arithmetic `IF` statement. The same statement label may appear more than once in the same arithmetic `IF` statement.
>
> Execution of an arithmetic `IF` statement causes evaluation of the expression `e` followed by a transfer of control. **The statement identified by `s1`, `s2`, or `s3` is executed next as the value of `e` is less than zero, equal to zero, or greater than zero, respectively.**

For the example in your question, from the last sentence above,

- If `J1-3 < 0` statement 20 will be executed
- If `J1-3 = 0` statement 20 will also be executed
- If `J1-3 > 0` statement 21 will be executed

**Edit**: A modern and much more readable way to write this would be:

```
if (J1-3 > 0) J1 = J1 - 3
if (J2-3 > 0) J2 = J2 - 3
```

Comment: No problem. Note that my edit is still valid FORTRAN 77 (and of course valid Fortran 90, 95 etc.). It makes use of a *logical if statement*. The other type of if statement is the *block if statement*.

Comment: Lowercase `if` is not standard FORTRAN 77 :)

Comment: Fortran used to be case insensitive ... indeed.. at least after punchcards ;)

Comment: And even more readable in the modern version to compare J1 to 3? `J1>3` At least, if you know J1 isn't overflowing its type.