# Older type IF structure in Fortran 77

Tags: if-statement, fortran, fortran77

I used to coding with Fortran 95, therefore I am not so familiar with Fortran 77. I have a Fortran 77 code which includes the following section:

```
      REAL*8 Xn, Xend

c     Skip......
      IF (Xn-Xend) 1, 7, 7
7     Xend = Xn
```

What is the function of `IF (Xn-Xend) 1, 7, 7`? How can I rewrite it to Fortran 90/95 form?

Comment: I don't think this is valid F77; the indentation of `Xend = Xn` makes one expect an `IF (condition) THEN` line before.

Comment: so maybe you could give us a minimal example of this that would compile?

Comment: It is an arithmetic if statement.  There are a few other questions on the same topic - have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/11124855/1234550 and see if that makes things clear.

Comment: @IanH Thanks! I have figured out what it is.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran]. And others with editing privileges  please add the tag there. This way I could not use the instaclose as duplicate.